# unable to load data from parquet files to hive external table

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet, bigdata

I have written below scala code to create parquet file

```
scala> case class Person(name:String,age:Int,sex:String)
defined class Person

scala> val data = Seq(Person("jack",25,"m"),Person("john",26,"m"),Person("anu",27,"f"))
data: Seq[Person] = List(Person(jack,25,m), Person(john,26,m), Person(anu,27,f))

scala> import  sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

scala> df.select("name","age","sex").write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save("sparksqloutput/person")
```

HDFS status:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls sparksqloutput/person
Found 4 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2017-08-14 23:03 sparksqloutput/person/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera        394 2017-08-14 23:03 sparksqloutput/person/_common_metadata
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera        721 2017-08-14 23:03 sparksqloutput/person/_metadata
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera        773 2017-08-14 23:03 sparksqloutput/person/part-r-00000-2dd2f334-1985-42d6-9dbf-16b0a51e53a8.gz.parquet
```

Then I have created an external hive table using command below

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE person (name STRING,age INT,sex STRING) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '/sparksqlouput/person/';
OK
Time taken: 0.174 seconds
hive> select * from person
    > ;
OK
Time taken: 0.125 seconds
```

But while run above select query no rows returned. Kindly someone help on this.

Comment: the scala statement to create dataframe df is missing in question. Can you lease add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the hive sql statement `'select * from <table>'` simply locates table directory where table data exist and dumps file contents from that `hdfs` directory.

In your case `select *` is not working it means location is not correct.

Please note, in scala your last statement contains `save("sparksqloutput/person")`, where `"sparksqloutput/person"` is relative path and it will expand to `"/user/<logged in username>/sparksqloutput/person"` (i.e. `"/user/cloudera/sparksqloutput/person"`).

Hence while creating hive table you should use `"/user/cloudera/sparksqloutput/person"` instead of `"/sparksqloutput/person"`. Practically `"/sparksqloutput/person"` does not exist and hence you did not get any output in `select * from person`.